# Software to share/host calendar and address book

Tags: untagged

I'm looking to synchronize my PIM data between several computers and devices, but I don't want to share my data with Google or other third parties. I have my own server running Debian.

I run openSUSE KDE on most of my computers (work, home, laptop) and Ubuntu Netbook on my netbook. I have a Symbian S60 phone, but will probably soon get an Android instead. What's the best and most easy-to-setup software I can run on my server, fitting my needs? How do I set it up? I would prefer a single solution for both address book and calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOGo](http://www.sogo.nu/english.html) does all of this.  I prefer it to other programs because its open source and doesn't restrict features between "community" and "paid" versions.

Comment: It even has a slick web interface, more than I could've hoped for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like [GroupOffice](http://www.group-office.com/) its a cool application and there is a community edition.